How is the Normal distribution made from real world data
I am a secondary school student and I'm trying to wrap around how people actually create and apply normal distribution in the real world .
From my limited knowledge common sense tells me that, they collect the raw data and they then go on to create a histogram out of it if this histogram is close enough to be a perfect bell curve (I'm assuming they determine this with other statistical measures like skewness etc), they then use the standard deviation and the mean values and plug that into the normal distribution function to get their actual bell curve.
Because even though things like height are normally distributed, I'm assuming practically in the real world when someone collects data they might find that the heights may not be normally distributed somewhere (like for example a town with loads of children etc). So in my head, I'm assuming scientists make a histogram to check first to see if it's roughly close enough to being a bell curve.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution_fitting

See also QQ-plot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot which is useful way to check for normality visually.

There isn't one standard way that scientists will use to decide if they should use a normal distribution to model the data. It's worth noting that data doesn't have to be normally distributed for the normal distribution to be useful, because even if heights aren't normally distributed, if $\bar{X}$ is the average height of $100$ random people, $\bar{X}$ will be normally distributed.

@ZoeAllen sorry I'm not sure what you mean when you said if Xbar is the average height of random 100 people then X bar will be normally distributed?

I was referencing the central limit theorem. The central limit theorem states that even if $X$ isn't normally distributed, the average $\bar{X}_n$ of $n$ samples from $X$ will get closer and closer to normally distributed as $n \to \infty$ (in some mathematically precise way). This is extremely important for statistics, because it means you can test a hypothesis without needing to know what the distribution of your data is (and in real life we usually don't know) using the normal distribution.

What this technique of finding the average of the mean of n number of samples referred to . I vaguely understand what you are saying, I came across something similar in Sample Means Hypothesis Testing which we use for normal distribution
